# how to allow a script to fire just after clicking on a link to show a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web application that will show a dialog box after clicking on a link. the problem is that the dialog height is very small when using IE10 as follow:-

[image]

Now the whole problem is with the inner style height = 45px. Because if I manually change the value to be 450px instead of 45px using the F12 developer tools, the dialog will be rendered correctly.

after trying many approaches the only option that works is to set a timer that fires each 2 seconds to reset the height, as follow:-

```
var interval = null; //Defines the start interval variable

$(document).ready(function () { // jQuery needed for this
    /* People Picker Fix Starts */
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") > -1) { // IE 10 Specific condition for People Picker Bug
       interval = setInterval(adjustPeoplePicker, 2000);
    }
    /* People Picker Fix Ends */
});

function adjustPeoplePicker() {
    if ($('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#resultcontent').length > 0) {
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#resultcontent').css('height', '350px');
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch').css('height', '350px');
       //clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

but i do not want to keep firing the script each2 seconds , so i modify my script to only fires when a user clicks on a link that have an imag, as follow:-

```
<script type= "application/javascript">
var interval = null; //Defines the start interval variable

$(document).ready(function () { // jQuery needed for this

    $('a img').on('click', adjustPeoplePicker);    /* People Picker Fix Ends */


function adjustPeoplePicker() {

    if ($('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#resultcontent').length > 0) {
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#resultcontent').css('height', '350px');
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch').css('height', '350px');
       //clearInterval(interval);
    }

}
}});
</script>
```

but this will not work, and the height will not be changed.

so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

**EDIT**
here is part of the markup for the dialog :-

```
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="16" height="16"><img width="8" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
            <td width="100%" height="20"><img width="8" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
            <td width="15" height="8"><img width="8" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="100%" height="20"><span><table style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody><tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td class="ms-descriptiontext" style="white-space: nowrap;"><label for="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl07_queryTextBox"><b>Find</b>&nbsp;</label></td><td style="width: 100%;"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl07$queryTextBox" class="ms-pickersearchbox" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl07_queryTextBox" accesskey="S" style="width: 100%;" onkeydown="var e=event; if(!e) e=window.event; if(!browseris.safari &amp;&amp; e.keyCode==13) { document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl07_queryButton').click(); return false; }" type="text" maxlength="1000" alwaysenablesilent="true"></td><td><div class="ms-browseimage"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl07$queryButton" title="Search" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl07_queryButton" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl07$queryButton", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="image" alt="Search" src="/_layouts/15/images/browse.png"></div></td><td><select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl07$viewPicker" class="ms-pickerdropdown" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl07_viewPicker">
            <option value="">List View</option>
            <option value="">Detailed View</option>

        </select></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table></span></td>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td width="15"><img width="15" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td><td class="ms-descriptiontext"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl09"></span></td><td width="15"><img width="15" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="ms-descriptiontext" style="color: red;">
                    <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl08"></span>
                </td>
            <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="100%">
            <td width="15"><img width="15" height="200" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
            <td height="100%">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" class="ms-pickerresultoutertable" id="ResultOuterTable" style="height: 202px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody><tr height="100%">
                        <td class="TreeContainer" id="SearchArea" style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; display: block;">
                <div class="ms-pickertreediv" id="MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch" style="height: 45px;"><ul class="TmtTree" id="MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch_ul"><li id="0"><div class="treenodediv" id="_Div2"><span id="_ImgContainer"><img width="16" height="1" tabindex="-1" class="ti" src="/_layouts/15/Images/blank.gif"></span><img width="4" height="20" title="Icon" id="ICN_2" alt="Icon" src="/_layouts/15/Images/blank.gif"><span class="tnn" id="TXN_2"><span class="ms-input" id="TXC_2"><span tabindex="0" id="LBL_2"></span><input tabindex="0" class="ms-input display-none" id="IPT_2"></span></span></div><ul id="0_ul"></ul></li></ul></div>
            </td>
            <td class="TreeContainer" id="BrowseArea" style="width: 0px; vertical-align: top; display: none;">
                <div class="ms-pickertreediv" id="MetadataTreeControlTreeBrowse" style="height: 0px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="ms-verticalAlignTop" id="ResultArea" style="width: 60%; vertical-align: top;">
                <div class="ms-pickerresultdiv" id="resultcontent" style="height: 45px;"><table class="pickerresulttable" id="resultTable" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white;" hidefocus="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspaceing="0" EditorControlClientId="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05"><tbody><tr class="ms-pickerresultheadertr"><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">Display Name</th><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">E-mail Address</th><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">Title</th><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">Department</th><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">Presence</th><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">Work Phone</th><th class="ms-ph" SortOrder="Asc">Location</th></tr><tr tabindex="0" class="ms-alternating" id="row0" resultRow="resultRow" entityXml='<Entities Append="False" Error="" Separator=";" MaxHeight="3"><Entity Key="i:0#.w|..." DisplayText="test" IsResolved="True" Description="i:0#.w|ddd\**"><ExtraData><ArrayOfDictionaryEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Email</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test@test.net</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Title</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Network Support Manager</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Department</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Network</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">SIPAddress</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test2@test.net</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">WorkPhone</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Location</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value></DictionaryEntry></ArrayOfDictionaryEntry></ExtraData><MultipleMatches /></Entity></Entities>' key="i:0#.w|addd"><td class="ms-pb">ttttt<a id="resultTable_row0_Link" href="javascript:"><img width="1" height="1" alt="ttttt" src="/_layouts/15/Images/blank.gif" border="0"></a></td><td class="ms-pb">test@test.net</td><td class="ms-pb">Network Support Manager</td><td class="ms-pb">Network</td><td class="ms-pb">test@test.net</td><td class="ms-pb"></td><td class="ms-pb"></td></tr><tr tabindex="0" class="ms-alternating" id="row1" resultRow="resultRow" entityXml='<Entities Append="False" Error="" Separator=";" MaxHeight="3"><Entity Key="i:0#.w|test" DisplayText="tttt" IsResolved="True" Description="i:0#.w|test"><ExtraData><ArrayOfDictionaryEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Email</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test.net</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Title</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Head of Support</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Department</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">IT Services</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">SIPAddress</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">test.net</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">WorkPhone</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Location</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value></DictionaryEntry></ArrayOfDictionaryEntry></ExtraData><MultipleMatches /></Entity></Entities>' key="i:0#.w|test"><td class="ms-pb">tttt<a id="resultTable_row0_Link" href="javascript:"><img width="1" height="1" alt="tttt" src="/_layouts/15/Images/blank.gif" border="0"></a></td><td class="ms-pb">FAl-test.net</td><td class="ms-pb">Head of Support</td><td class="ms-pb">IT Services</td><td class="ms-pb">test.net</td><td class="ms-pb"></td><td class="ms-pb"></td></tr><tr tabindex="0" class="ms-alternating" id="row2" resultRow="resultRow" entityXml='<Entities Append="False" Error="" Separator=";" MaxHeight="3"><Entity Key="i:0#.w|atttt" DisplayText="tttt" IsResolved="True" Description="i:0#.w|attt"><ExtraData><ArrayOfDictionaryEntry xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Email</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">ttt</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Title</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">COO</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Department</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">Directors</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">SIPAddress</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string">ttt</Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">WorkPhone</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value></DictionaryEntry><DictionaryEntry><Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Location</Key><Value xsi:type="xsd:string"></Value></DictionaryEntry></ArrayOfDictionaryEntry></ExtraData><MultipleMatches /></Entity></Entities>' key="i:0#.w|ad-tttt"><td class="ms-pb">tttt<a id="resultTable_row0_Link" href="javascript:"><img width="1" height="1" alt="ttt" src="/_layouts/15/Images/blank.gif" border="0"></a></td><td class="ms-pb">tttt</td><td class="ms-pb">COO</td><td class="ms-pb">Directors</td><td class="ms-pb">tt</td><td class="ms-pb"></td>

//code goes here for the dialog options
</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
            </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
            <td width="15"><img width="15" height="200" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="14"><img width="1" height="5" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_EditorRow" style="display: none; position: absolute;">
    <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$AddSel" disabled="disabled" class="ms-NarrowButtonHeightWidth" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_AddSel" accesskey="A" onclick="addSelected_Click();" type="button" value="Add ->"></td>
                        <td width="10"><img width="4" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23"></td>
                        <td width="100%"><span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;" showentitydisplaytextintextbox="0" eeaftercallbackclientscript="" invalidate="false" allowtypein="false" showdatavalidationerrorborder="false" prefercontenteditablediv="true" moreitemstext="More Names..." allowempty="1" nomatchestext="<No Matching Names>" value="" removetext="Remove" editoroldvalue=""><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$hiddenSpanData" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_hiddenSpanData" type="hidden" value=""><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$OriginalEntities" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_OriginalEntities" type="hidden" value="<Entities />"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$HiddenEntityKey" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_HiddenEntityKey" type="hidden"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$HiddenEntityDisplayText" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_HiddenEntityDisplayText" type="hidden"><table class="ms-usereditor" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_OuterTable" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr valign="bottom">
            <td valign="top"><table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_containerCell"><div tabindex="0" title="People Picker" class="ms-inputuserfield ms-inputBox" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_upLevelDiv" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" style="height: 20px; -ms-overflow-x: hidden; -ms-word-wrap: break-word;" spellcheck="false" aria-multiline="true" onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05', 3, false, event);" onkeyup="return onKeyUpRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');" onclick="onClickRw(true, true,event,'ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');" onchange="updateControlValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');" ondragstart="canEvt(event);" oncopy="docopy('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05',event);" onpaste="dopaste('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05',event);" onfocusin="StoreOldValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05'); saveOldEntities('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05'); Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" onfocusout="if(typeof(ExternalCustomControlCallback)=='function'){ if(ShouldCallCustomCallBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05',event)){if(!ValidatePickerControl('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05')){ShowValidationError();return false;}else {ExternalCustomControlCallback('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');}}} Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" name="upLevelDiv" autopostback="0" prefercontenteditablediv="true" rows="1"></div><textarea name="ctl00$PlaceHolderDialogBodySection$ctl05$downlevelTextBox" title="People Picker" class="ms-inputuserfield ms-inputBox" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_downlevelTextBox" style="width: 100%; display: none; position: absolute;" onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05', 3, false, event);" onkeyup="return onKeyUpRw('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');" onfocus="StoreOldValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05'); saveOldEntities('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05'); Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" onblur="if(typeof(ExternalCustomControlCallback)=='function'){ if(ShouldCallCustomCallBack('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05',event)){if(!ValidatePickerControl('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05')){ShowValidationError();return false;}else {ExternalCustomControlCallback('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');}}} Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" onchange="updateControlValue('ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05');" rows="1" cols="20" autopostback="0" renderascontenteditablediv="true"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span class="ms-error" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_ctl05_errorLabel"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </td>
    <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle with the html, css and code?

Comment: .after('click', ?? I think it should be .on('click',

Comment: welcome to developing for IE ;-D

Comment: who or what is setting the css height property to 45px? might this be some other part of your applications code? i don't think IE is inserting that property by itself.

Comment: What happens if you set the height to `auto`?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef yes that is correct , i modifed my question,, i was testing the script so i chnaged the .on to be.after !!

Comment: If you can, increase the size of the `<td>` the dialog should be shown in.

Comment: @Press can you adivce more on this please?

Comment: The HTML and table structure is completely nuts. My best guess is to try and set the `<td>` with the class `ms-verticalAlignTop`'s height to something that you want. Say `450px` line you mentioned in your edit.

Comment: At this point, I think you will need to provide a fiddle or active site duplicating the problem to get an answer.

Comment: Also, this maybe a better site for you: [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem, why not just use CSS:

```
.ms-pickerresultdiv[style]{
    height:auto !important;
    max-height:350px !important;
}
```

Or just

```
.ms-pickerresultdiv[style]{
    height:350px !important;
}
```

If you need to increase the size of the parent table cell, this should do it:

```
#row2 td:last-child{
    height:350px;
}
```

Or based on your script, override these two elements:

```
#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch,
#resultcontent[style]{
    height:350px !important;
}
```

Although I can't find the `#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch` element within your posted code.

[**Here's a fiddle with all that**](http://jsfiddle.net/05cp4t6w/)

Either of those should override the inline style.

Comment: i already tried adding these #resultcontent {
    height: 400px !important
}
.ms-pickerresultdiv {
    height: 400px !important
}

#resultcontent{height:350px !important;} but they did not have any effect

Comment: also using your code will not have any effect.. i need to keep firing a script for this to get fixed.. not sure why!!

Comment: @johnG Post the rendered code. If what I wrote doesn't work, something else is wrong. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swwu53hs/)

Comment: thanks i edit my question is related markup ,, hope this will help

Comment: @johnG I updated my answer to include sizing the parent table cell, and a link to a functioning demo.

Comment: first off all can you update the fiddle code to my updated code, as i forget to remove user names from it . i edited my original question with a code that hide the real name,, sorry about that.

Comment: i tried adding the following #row2 td:last-child{
    height:450px;
} but seems it will not have any effect,,, i can not understand what is going on ... the only approach that seems to be working is having a timer as i mentioned in my original code..

Comment: @johnG -- i changed the linked fiddle to your new code. Also, in your script, you are setting the size of an element that is not part of your posted code: `#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch`...I updated my answer to use the to element identifiers you use in your script.

Comment: yes this is correct but even if i remove    $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch').css('height', '350px'); still the script will work as expected ,, this is responsible for expanding a vertical line ,, but if i remove it still the script will work well...

Comment: thanks for your help, but even "#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch,
#resultcontent[style]{
    height:350px !important;
}" will not have any effect...

Answer (score 1):

a style property on an element will not be set by the browser automatically. some other part of your application code is setting the div's style `height` property to `45px`. the style property has priority over other stylesheets.

try to isolate and remove that code.

Comment: this is a sharepoint web site so i do not have control over the application or i am not 100% aware of the application.. the strange thing is that the dialog will show well on firefox, chrome. even on IE10 if i chnage the document mode to be IE9 standards instead of defualt the dialog will be rendered correctly..

Comment: is the style attribute also present on the other browsers? it would help to see the whole thing.

Comment: on Firefox the height will be set to 375 px !!

Comment: @johnG also in the style tag? than for sure some other javascript code is setting this. it is probably calculating the height based on innerHeight, window height or something similar. IE has some different measurement getters. this might be the root of the problem. anyway you need to find the code that is setting the height.